# PowerShell String Replace function with variable value

Tags: windows, powershell, ps1

can we mention the variable in - replace function
example:

```
$value="V2"
$prop="Groovy=V3"

$prop -replace "(?<conf>Groovy)=(?<version>[vV]\d)" , "${conf}=${value}"
```

Comment: ``$prop -replace "(?<conf>Groovy)=(?<version>[vV]\d)" , "`${conf}=${value}"`` or ``$prop -replace "(?<conf>Groovy)=(?<version>[vV]\d)" , "`$1=${value}"``

Answer (score 3):

`${conf}` *is* the correct syntax for referencing a capture in a regex substitution string, but it's *also* a valid PowerShell variable expression - so you need to replace the double-quotes around the substitute string with single-quotes to prevent PowerShell from attempting to expand the variables before the string is passed to the `-replace` operator:

```
$value="V2"
$prop="Groovy=V3"

$prop -replace "(?<conf>Groovy)=(?<version>[vV]\d)" , ('${conf}=' + ${value})
```

Another option is to escape the `$` with a backtick:

```
$prop -replace "(?<conf>Groovy)=(?<version>[vV]\d)" ,"`${conf}=${value}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Powershell 7 version with the scriptblock second argument.  It may not be easier, but no special escaping of the "conf" named capture group is required.

```
$value = 'V2'
'Groovy=V3' -replace '(?<conf>Groovy)=[vV]\d', 
  { $_.groups['conf'].value + '=' + $value }

Groovy=V2
```

Or simply the first capture group:

```
$value = 'V2'
'Groovy=V3' -replace '(Groovy)=[vV]\d', { $_.groups[1].value + '=' + $value }

Groovy=V2
```